# How to get rid of Yeoman favicon for localhost:8000

Tags: localhost, yeoman, yeoman-generator, simplehttpserver

I know that I can set a favicon inside my index.html, but the Yeoman icon shows up even when I have no server running

He doesn't show up for localhost:3000 or any other number

How do I get rid of the Yeoman icon for localhost:8000?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your browser cache. Favicons gets cache for a very long time and are not refetch each time a browser access a web page.